# taxonomy query to output slugs instead IDs

Tags: multi-taxonomy-query, advanced-taxonomy-queries

So I got a custom search form with three dropdowns containing three different custom taxonomies.

The problem is, I'd need the taxonomy slugs in the address for the search to fuction properly, because now I only get the IDs. If I have product category with the name/slug of **50**, when searching it outputs the taxonomy ID which is **6** in the address.

Like so:

`/?s=&product_category=6&product_maksuaika=14&product_ikaraja=0`

When it should be:

```
/?s=&product_category=50&product_maksuaika=14&product_ikaraja=0
```

Same goes for all of the three taxonomies I have.

Here's my function:

```
function my_dropdown($name, $taxonomy = 'category') {
$defaults = array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'id'       => $name,
    'name'     => $name,
    'show_option_none' => ' - Select - ',
    'selected' => get_query_var($name)
);

wp_dropdown_categories($defaults); 
 } 


add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_customsearch'); 
function my_customsearch() {   
  global $wp_query;
  if ( !$wp_query->is_search ) {
    return false;
  }

  $tax_query = array();
  $operacion = get_query_var('product_category');
  $ubicacion = get_query_var('product_maksuaika');
  $precio    = get_query_var('product_ikaraja');

  // first dropdown

  if (!empty($operacion) && $operacion > 0) {
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => $operacion
     );
  }

  // second dropdown

  if (!empty($ubicacion) && $ubicacion > 0) {
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_maksuaika',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => $ubicacion
    );
  }

  // third dropdown

  if (!empty($precio) && $precio > 0) {
      $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_maksuaika',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => $ubicacion
      );

  if ( sizeof($tax_query) > 0 ) {
      $tax_query['relation'] = 'AND';
      $wp_query->query_vars['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
  }

return false; 
} 

// add my custom query vars 
add_filter('query_vars', 'mycustom_query_vars'); 

function mycustom_query_vars($query_vars) {
  $query_vars[] = 'operacion';
  $query_vars[] = 'ubicacion';
  $query_vars[] = 'precio';

  return $query_vars; 
 }
```

Simply changing the field to slugs or names in the array does not do the trick.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing stands out as 'wrong' - though you do have a few errors:

- The third tax_query conditional is missing a closing bracket
- The third tax_query should be querying `precio` not `$ubicacion`.
- Cast the ID variables as integers

I'd suggest putting WordPress into debug mode to highlight any syntax errors. Try doing it for only one taxonomy first, and then add the others in. If using WP3.3+ I would also suggest the following set up:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_customsearch'); 
function my_customsearch($query) {   

    if(! $query->is_main_query() || ! $query->is_search )
       return;

    $tax_query = array();
    $operacion = (int) get_query_var('product_category');

    // first dropdown
    if (! empty($operacion) && $operacion > 0) {
       $tax_query[] = array(
         'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
         'field'    => 'id',
         'terms'    => $operacion
       );
    }

   if ( sizeof($tax_query) > 0 ) {
      $tax_query['relation'] = 'AND';
      $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
   }

}
```

Keep in mind this will replace any tax query that is part of the main search.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the errors, guess that's what you get when you work with something for too long. The search works like it should now with your code so thank you very much.